# Print DataBase Schema in Sql Server Compact Edition

Tags: schema, sql-server-ce

I Want Print DataBase Schema in "Microsoft Sql Server Compact Edition".
Maybe Exist Some Tools For it.

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLMetal to create a dbml file with your SQL Server CE objects and print that.

Keep in mind that you cannot just drag the tables over to the designer like with LINQ to SQL, you have to use SQLMetal instead.

There is a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Compact_LINQ.aspx) on this subject over at code project...

Answer (score 1):

Buy http://primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html